# spock: what's wrong with this mocking

Tags: mocking, spock

Given following interface:

```
interface Bundle {
    String getName()

    String getVersion()
}
```

and following method:

```
String log(Bundle b) {
    return "${b.getName()}: ${b.getVersion()}"
}
```

this spock test is failing:

```
def "my test"() {
        given:
        def bundle = Mock(Bundle)
        bundle.getName() >> "name"
        bundle.getVersion() >> "1.0.0"

        when:
        def x = log(bundle)

        then:
        x == "name: 1.0.0"
        1 * bundle.getName()
        1 * bundle.getVersion()

    }
```

here is the error:

```
condition not satisfied:
x == "name: 1.0.0"
| |
| false
| 8 differences (27% similarity)
| n(ull): (null-)
| n(ame): (1.0.0)
null: null
```

If i remove two verifications (`1 * bundle.getName()` and `1 * bundle.getVersion()`) the test will be green.

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking and stubbing of the same invocation need to happen together (either in the `given` or `then` block):

```
...
then:
1 * bundle.getName() >> "name"
1 * bundle.getVersion() >> "1.0.0"
x == "name: 1.0.0"
```

[Combining Mocking and Stubbing](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#combining-mocking-and-stubbing) in the [Spock Reference Documentation](http://docs.spockframework.org) explains this in more detail.

An alternative is to get rid of the mocking part (`1 * bundle.getName()` etc.), which may not be all that necessary/helpful here.

Comment: In this case, I wont be able to have a common mocking which is used by multiple test methods. for example, creating mocking interactions in "setup" method and then stubbing in several test methods. am i right?

Comment: You are right in that you can only override the whole interaction (and that has to happen in a `then` block). You can't declare the mocking part earlier and the stubbing part later (for one and the same interaction).